# jQuery fancyform on dependent dropdowns

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, fancyform

I'm using jQuery fancyform on an app I'm building using php [simplemvcframework](http://simplemvcframework.com/).
On the main page I have 2 dependent dropdowns. The 1st selectbox is filled on page load and the plugin works, but since the 2nd selectbox is only populated after selecting an option from the 1st (via an ajax call to an API), it doesn't get transformed.
What fancyform does is append 2 nested ul's after the selectbox and the 2nd  holds the options as li's. As the 2nd selectbox has no options on page load, I need to attach the transformation after. 
I tried calling the transformSelect() method on the change event of the 1st and/or the success function of the ajax call, but with no success.
Is there anything I'm missing?

My 1st dropdown change event:

```js
$('#ddlMarca').change(function(){
      var idmarca = $('#ddlMarca').val();
      console.log('IDMarca: '+idmarca);
        var strURL="<?php echo DIR;?>apimodelos";
      if(idmarca != 0 || idmarca != '')
      {
         $.ajax({
           type:'post',
           url:strURL,
           data:{idmarca:idmarca},
           cache:false,
           success: function(returndata){
            console.log('Modelos: '+returndata);
              $('#ddlModelos').html(returndata);

              $("#ddlModelos").transformSelect({
          dropDownClass: "tmSelect tmSelect2",
          showFirstItemInDrop: true,
          acceptManualInput: false,
          useManualInputAsFilter : false
        });
           }
         });
      }
 
});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it.

Instead of calling the `transformSelect()` method on the change event of the 1st dropdown, I have to call `.transformSelect('repaint')`